# How to disable password prompt from ssh client side?

Tags: openssh

I have a script that relies on public/private key ssh authentication.  The problem is that some systems are misconfigured and do not have the proper ssh public/private key trust set up.  When that happens `ssh` ask me for a password blocking the script's execution.  I have tried this command:

```
sudo ssh -o "PasswordAuthentication=no" -o "ChallengeResponseAuthentication=no" root@last-call
```

But I still get prompted for the root password.

Comment: After trial and error I found the option I needed.  `"PreferredAuthentications=publickey"`

Comment: is that better than the solution proposed? (BatchMode)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The canonical way to do this is with the `BatchMode` option:

```
ssh -o BatchMode=yes …
```

According to the [manual](http://www.openbsd.org/cgi-bin/man.cgi/OpenBSD-current/man5/ssh_config.5):

> If set to “yes”, passphrase/password querying will be disabled. This option is useful in scripts and other batch jobs where no user is present to supply the password.

I would have expected the combination of `PasswordAuthentication=no` and `ChallengeResponseAuthentication=no` to be enough though. `ssh -vv` might yield a clue.

Comment: That works too! `$ sudo ssh last-call-2
Password: 
$ sudo ssh -o "BatchMode=yes" last-call-2
Permission denied (gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,publickey,password,keyboard-interactive).
`