# Can I disable ssh password authentication on the client side?

Tags: ssh

I'm connecting to an SSH server where I'm not fully in control of the sshd configuration. The server allows both public-key auth and password auth, but I want to prevent my SSH *client* from switching over to password auth, even when public key auth fails.

I've tried adding `PasswordAuthentication no` to the server entry in `~/.ssh/config` but it has no distinguishable effect.

Is it even possible?

I understand that this will not provide any additional security. I'm seeking to do this solely for UX purposes, to avoid certain situations where some applications get stuck waiting for a password.

Answer (score 5):

`ssh` won't prompt if in batchmode:

```
ssh -oBatchMode=yes you@theotherhost command
```

You could set

```
alias ssh /usr/bin/ssh -oBatchMode=yes
```

in your `.bashrc` which will disable password authentication from the client side for interactive sessions. (unless you do `/us/bin/ssh`)

A more elaborate scheme could be:

- make sure `/usr/local/bin` is in the `PATH` before `/usr/bin`
- create a file `/usr/local/bin/ssh` with:

```
#!/bin/bash
/usr/bin/ssh $*
```

- `chmod a+rx /usr/local/bin/ssh`

None of this is foolproof, however.

Answer (score 1):

**Client side command or `~/.ssh/config`:**

Here you can find some possibilities for your solution

[To disable password authentication for the current ssh connection attempt](https://serverfault.com/a/61919/956923)

> To disable password authentication for the current ssh connection attempt, pass this option on the command line:
> `-o PasswordAuthentication=no`

> To disable password authentication for all future connections to any host add the following to your ~/.ssh/config:
> `PasswordAuthentication no`

> On the command line (or ~/.ssh/config) you can set PreferredAuthentications.
> `PreferredAuthentications=publickey`

[How to disable password prompt from ssh client side?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/264472/how-to-disable-password-prompt-from-ssh-client-side)

> The canonical way to do this is with the BatchMode option:

`ssh -o BatchMode=yes …`

**Remote/server side `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`:**

If don't want to use a password you can do changes in the `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` on the remote machine on `PasswordAuthentication no`

**Some general settings in sshd_config remote machine:**

```
PermitRootLogin no          # No root login
PasswordAuthentication no   # No password login
PermitEmptyPasswords no     # No empty password
PubkeyAuthentication yes    # login with public key
```

After edit restart your service